# Sucuri - Outdated Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, security

I have received a below mail from sucuri (Website Security)

> **Outdated Software**
>   Found outdated Magento inside: ./app/Mage.php -
>   Version: 1.9.1.0 - Please update asap.

Please help need to Update a magento version or any other solution we have to remove this security warning.

Comment: Either update Magento to the latest 1.9.3 version or at least make sure, that all security patches for 1.9.1 are applied. You find them at https://magento.com/tech-resources/download ("Archive" tab, scroll down to "Magento Community Edition Patches - 1.x")

Answer (score 2):

You can download the newest version [here](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download) (release archive) and for magento 1 the newest version is `1.9.3.3`

Make sure to test out the updates before on a staging environment.

You can also install just the security patches from there but that might not erase the warning.